# Do spambots directly POST to server or fill out HTML forms?

Tags: php, captcha, spam-prevention

I'm looking at using an alternative to Captcha (or Recaptcha) for the registration form on website I'm working on.

I believe Captcha's negatively affect UX. I was looking into using hidden fields but apparently they're not effective at all (Reference: http://radio.javaranch.com/davo/2008/10/15/1224063498569.html)

A comment on that article states:

> As someone that writes CAPTCHA crackers as part of my job (no, not for
>   spamming), I can assure you that a hidden field would in no way trip
>   me up. As another poster mentioned, I check the over the wire traffic,
>   and don't pay much attention to what happens to be in the HTML of the
>   form.

This led me to believe that spambots make direct POST requests to the server, rather than request the form and fill it out.

If that is the case, what if I create a hidden, read-only field that I pre-populate with a hash stored in SESSION. When the user submits the form, I can compare the values. Would this work as a way to keep away spambots, or am I overseeing something?

If the form is never requested, I, of course, would not find any hash stored in session and could thus ignore the request.

Comment: You're making at least three assumptions here that you should reexamine:

 1. That all CAPTCHA crackers use the same techniques;
 2. That you've had an idea that people who build CAPTCHAs professionally and people who crack them professionally have not (and couldn't figure out);
 3. That your site is going to be a target for spammers soon enough for you to be devoting development time to this right now.

They don't, you haven't, and it isn't.

Comment: @Jordan: I agree that I'm making the first two assumptions. Unfortunately, the third one isn't one of them. I'm still working on the site, completed the registration functionality last week, and already have 3 obvious bots in my database.

Comment: @xbonez Your claim here in the comments pretty much disproves the 'belief' you were lead to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding another field with a challenge tied to a server-side session variable is a good approach; it would require considerably more effort on the side of spam bots, i.e. they have to load and parse the form, fill it out and make another request (sending along the necessary cookies).

You could also consider adding JavaScript to modify the given challenge and modify it in a certain way. The attacker would then need to find out what your code does before they can replicate it in an automated fashion. Transformations could be a simple `rot13` or more complicated `xor` operations. Things like `md5`, `sha1` are established algorithms so those are a poor choice; it has to be custom.

Of course, if an attacker is bound on targeting your site, there's not much you can do to prevent spam from coming in; that's the ugly truth. For instance, they could run [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and circumvent all the JavaScript protection you have carefully built in.

Comment: I like the idea of bringing JS into the mix as well. When you said 'use Javascript to modify the challenge', what did you have in mind? Something like, perhaps, reverse the hash?

Comment: I agree, in general the whole point of captchas etc. is to increase the computational work for the spammer so that spamming becomes more expensive. Having some computation done in the browser goes towards this target.

Comment: @xbonez I've added an example of 'modifying challenge' in the answer

Comment: Thanks. If I go with something relatively complicated and obfuscate / minify the code, it should take considerable effort to reverse-engineer it, and I doubt my site would be worth that trouble. Unless of course, as sundowned mentions, the bot is run as a browser plugin and is capable of executing JS.

Comment: @xbonez yep, reference to Selenium added :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I suspect that you already have spammers specifically targeting your site. If you've manually implemented login and registration, it's unlikely that a spambot would have logic capable of signing up without being specifically tailored to your forms.

The other solutions are good, and while they will help, none of them will prevent even a moderately determined spammer. Plenty of spambots operate as browser plugins, so trusting that a spambot can't evaluate JavaScript or won't call for the form in the first place is unlikely to help you for very long. At the very least, a CAPTCHA for registration (and perhaps for each post, or whatever your site does, until the account is manually approved) is probably going to be mandatory.

I know you don't want to impact the user experience, **but spam messages and accounts are far more detrimental to UX than CAPTCHAs.** Bite the bullet and do everything you can to slow spammers down, or your users will look elsewhere.

Granted, CAPTCHAs are not complete solutions - there exists software that can solve them (in some cases) more accurately than humans. They, like enriched breakfast cereal, are merely part of this complete breakfast - and no one in their right mind would start the day off with SPAM. ;)

Moderating new users will likely prove to be very helpful.

Comment: Yeah, it seems I'm going to have to go with something more aggressive. I'm thinking of going with email verification. Spambots aren't capable of verifying accounts, are they?

Comment: Email verification? Of course they are capable of that, on the whole - It's a trivial problem. Not all spambots can, but keep in mind that plenty of spam occurs after a HUMAN user sets up the account

Comment: Think rationally: if there was a method of verification that a bot couldn't pass, EVERYONE would use it. There wouldn't be SPAM anymore. Therefore, nothing is foolproof.

Comment: It's like this: each verification step adds a level of complexity. The more complex it is, the less spambots will be able to navigate it. You want enough obstructions in the paths of spammers that they'll focus on sites that are less well defended than yours. If you're really paranoid you could require SMS authentication or something but that's not foolproof either thanks to SMS gateways.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the bot. If someone targeted your site, this can be circumvented very easily:

1. Request page with form and filled in session value
2. Fill out the form and submit.

I would say it is almost no protection.

Sadly I'm not too familiar with current state of bots and how they work, so this is just my input on how easy it would be to work around this implementation.

Comment: It's true that a bot targeted at my website could circumvent the protection. An advanced bot could parse CSS and recognize hidden fields as well. I'd settle for 'the most effective' method since a 'perfect method' probably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Different spambots uses different ways.

But most flexible spam bots:
1. request page with form
2. read what fields it contains
3. send POST request with found fields with some filled values

You cann't sure, that all bots can find and leave filed your "form-session-token" input. You cann't sure that all bots can use javascript (another way to protect - add required field onsubmit with js). But bots much and different.